# Firefox notifications with x-dwm became intrusive around 122.0

Tags: firefox, x-dwm

Before I turn to the esoteric mailing lists I present you with an opportunity to lower my already tarnished reputation: 
my Firefox notifications using DWM used to be exemplary - a small non-intrusive window at the top right that then went away by itself quickly.
From around FF 122.0 on they now create a whole new window that also becomes master, thus stealing focus and eg interrupting while I might be typing somewhere else.

Is there someone who knows what FF setting might have changed that affected this behaviour please?

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an authoritative answer as maybe a workaround/gordian knot cut but I went over to start using `dunst` as a notification daemon instead and it was pretty straightforward. Just relying on the default behavior of the Window manager + browser turned out to be unsatisfactory in the end.